# Error thrown from TCP/IP Server when client disconnects

Tags: vb.net, tcplistener

I have the following code as part of a TCP/IP Server. The program works well but I noticed that a System.IO.IOException error is thrown on the `Server` as a `Client` disconnects. (I'm literally disconnecting the client.)

```
Private Sub ReadAllClient()
    Try
        RaiseEvent getMessage(New StreamReader(listClient.GetStream).ReadLine)
        listClient.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReadAllClient), Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseEvent clientLogout(Me)
    End Try
End Sub
```

(EDIT: Error message details)

```
System.IO.IOException: 'Unable to read data from the transport 
connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in 
your host machine.'
```

This error isn't normally a part of VS 2017 and just threw it on to find the cause and it is this Try/Catch statement. (The Catch part is definitely working... but the error is being thrown.)

Should I be concerned that this exception is being thrown? Or is it safe enough to ignore?

Comment: Provide specifics on the error message

Comment: @CaiusJard: Added. I'm starting to think this might be nothing but normal as I had to literally get VS to break on this particular error.

Comment: Looks like a normal "something at or between the client and the server cut the connection" - I'd ignore it